# Directing Qualtrics question to a particular folder

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Does anyone know if it is possible to write a code that directs a Qualtrics question to a particular folder? (and that can be modified to different folders?)

For example, participant 1 corresponds to folder1. Therefore, I would like Qualtrics to use the images from folder1 in the question.

Next would be participant 2, which corresponds to folder2, and I would like Qualtrics to use the images from folder2 in the question.

Any help or advice would be very appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Qualtrics Folders are for organizational purposes only...there is no programmatic way to reference folders.